# Installed RED plugin.But, option to create Robot project is not appearing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, robotframework

Installed RED plugin to the eclipse version Mars. But, option to create Robot project is not appearing. Can help me to create a robot framework automation script?

Answer (score 2):

If you installed everything correctly you should find it in *New Project* dialog. Just select *File->New...->Other...* and then search for 'Robot'.

[image]